# Extract nested property inside Aeson object

Tags: haskell, aeson

How can I get a nested property using `Data.Aeson`?

For example, when decoding an arbitrary JSON string using `Value` like this:

```
decode "{\"foo\":{\"bar0\":\"foobar0\",
                  \"bar1\":\"foobar1\"}}" :: Maybe Value
```

I end up with this:

```
Just (Object (fromList [("foo",Object (fromList [("bar1",String "foobar1"),("bar0",String "foobar0")]))]))
```

Now, how can I write a function `[String] -> Object -> Maybe Value` that will extract the `Value`, if any, arrived at by following the provided list of properties?

This function should be used like so:

```
extractProperty ["foo", "bar0"] (Object (fromList [("foo",Object (fromList [("bar1",String "foobar1"),("bar0",String "foobar0")]))]))

==> Just (String "foobar0")

extractProperty ["foo", "bar0", "baz"] (Object (fromList [("foo",Object (fromList [("bar1",String "foobar1"),("bar0",String "foobar0")]))]))

==> Nothing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution makes use of the `lens` and `lens-aeson` packages:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

import Control.Lens (view,pre,ix)        -- from lens
import Control.Lens.Reified (ReifiedTraversal(..))
import Data.Aeson           -- from aeson
import Data.Aeson.Lens (_Object)  -- from lens-aeson
import Data.Text            -- form text

instance Monoid (ReifiedTraversal s s s s) where
    mempty = Traversal id
    mappend (Traversal t1) (Traversal t2) = Traversal (t1 . t2) 

extractProperty :: [Text] -> Object -> Maybe Value 
extractProperty keys o = 
    view (pre telescope) (Object o)
  where
    telescope = runTraversal $ foldMap (\k -> Traversal $ _Object . ix k) keys
```

`ReifiedTraversal` is simply a newtype around a `Traversal`, we define a `Monoid` instance on it to allow easy composition of traversals that start and end in the same type (similar to how the [`Endo`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Endo) monoid works).

In our case, the traversal `_Object . ix k` goes from `Value` to `Value`. [`ix`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.9.1/docs/Control-Lens-At.html#v:ix) comes from `Control.Lens.At` and indexes on the map of properties of an `Object`.

We extract the first result of the composed traversal (if it exists) with the [`pre`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.9.1/docs/Control-Lens-Fold.html#v:pre) function.

**Edit:** As @cchalmers mentions in his comment, there's no need to declare an orphan instance, it works fine just with `Endo`. Also `key k` is the same as `_Object . ix k`.

Here's a version of `extractProperty` that doesn't use `lens` and instead relies on composing a list of kleisli arrows `Value -> Maybe Value` using `foldr`:

```
import qualified Data.HashMap.Strict as HM

extractProperty :: [T.Text] -> Object -> Maybe Value 
extractProperty keys o = telescope keys (Object o)
  where
    telescope = foldr (>=>) return . map maybeKey 
    maybeKey k v = case v of 
        Object o -> HM.lookup k o  
        _ -> Nothing
```

Perhaps `lens` was a bit overkill in this case.

Comment: Why not just use `Endo` instead of writing a misleading orphan? Also `_Object . ix k = key i`. Here's a more succinct version `extract ks = preview (alaf Endo foldMap key ks) . Object`.

Comment: This is elegant but seems like overkill (possibly because I haven't learned lenses yet). Is there a simpler, possibly recursive solution to this?

Comment: @cchalmers Can you expand upon your suggestions in a new answer?

Comment: @cchalmers I had the mistaken impression that `Endo` didn't work well with traversals/lenses.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, using monadic bind:

```
import Data.Text (Text)
import qualified Data.HashMap.Strict as HM

extractProperty :: [Text] -> Value -> Maybe Value
extractProperty []     v          = Just v
extractProperty (k:ks) (Object o) = HM.lookup k o >>= prop ks
extractProperty _      _          = Nothing
```